# Get random boolean true/false in PHP

Tags: php, random, boolean

What would be the most elegant way to get a random boolean true/false in PHP?

I can think of:

```
$value = (bool)rand(0,1);
```

But does casting an integer to boolean bring any disadvantages?

Or is this an "official" way to do this?

Comment: `mt_rand()` is better than `rand()`, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14079997)

Comment: It's a one liner that does the exact task you need. What kind disadvantages do you have in mind?

Comment: For readability I would recommend either `rand(0,1) == 1` or `rand(0,1) > 0`. Implicit casting, although documented, is kind of hard to read imo.

Comment: This is what I'd use: `array_rand(array(True, False))`.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly cast to a bool if you only want 'truthiness'. 0 evaluates to falsy, 1 to truthy.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

If you don't wish to have a boolean cast (not that there's anything wrong with that) you can easily make it a boolean like this:

```
$value = rand(0,1) == 1;
```

Basically, if the random value is `1`, yield `true`, otherwise `false`. Of course, a value of `0` or `1` already *acts* as a boolean value; so this:

```
if (rand(0, 1)) { ... }
```

Is a perfectly valid condition and will work as expected.

Alternatively, you can use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) for the random number generation (it's an improvement over `rand()`). You could even go as far as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` with this code:

```
$value = ord(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1)) >= 0x80;
```

#### Update

In PHP 7.0 you will be able to use [`random_int()`](http://php.net/random_int), which generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers:

```
$value = (bool)random_int(0, 1);
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but why not use a type-safe comparison (`===`) vs the casting one (`==`) on your first code example?

Comment: @NerdOfCode `rand(0, 1)` always returns an integer value, so you don't strictly need a type-safe comparison; things would be different if there's a chance that the function returns values of other types, e.g. `false` or `null` which would get typecast to `0`.

Answer (score 8):

I use a simply

```
rand(0,1) < 0.5
```

Comment: This is also useful to fine tune the randomness and make random bools that aren't just evenly random 50% of the time, such as `rand(0, 1) < 0.25`.

Comment: I think that would need to be `rand(0, 100) < 25` to be effective @neave

Comment: It's worth noting that strictly speaking this method is slightly biased towards `false` as `true` = 0 - 0.499999 and `false` = 0.5 - 1.0 (0.000001 more).

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness, if you want to use it in an `if` condition, there is no need to cast, since `0` is considered `false` and `mt_rand` produces random integers in the range:

```php
if (mt_rand(0,1)) { // 0 = false, 1 = true
  // whatever
}
```

Note: `mt_rand` is 4x faster than `rand`

> The `mt_rand()` function is a drop-in replacement for the older `rand()`. It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the "Mersenne Twister", which **will produce random numbers four times faster** than what the average libc `rand()` provides.
> (Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: [As of 7.1.0, rand() has been made an alias of mt_rand().](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases)  PHP7.1 was released 01 Dec 2016.

Answer (score 1):

php stan recomended

```
1 === random_int(0, 1)
```

Comment: It depends on what you need, performance wise I think it takes more to use `random_int()` over `rand()`, more on this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228718/php-rand-vs-random-int

Comment: How is PHPStan related to the given question?