# php shuffle a pack of cards

Tags: php, string, random, permutation, shuffle

I would like to use php to create a collection of random bridge hands. I thought that I could encode an ordered pack of cards as the string `$deal` below (I like it that there are 52 letters when considering both upper and lower case). I discovered the php function `str_shuffle`. So I thought that I could do the following:

```
$pack = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$shuffledPack = str_shuffle($pack);
```

This gives me the desired output.

My question is: does `str_shuffle` give output that follows a uniform distribution for each and every possible permutation?

Comment: Strange pack of cards you have there ;-)

Comment: It does have the `A` for the `ace`, the `J` for `jack`, `Q` for `queen` and `K` for `king` ;-) @Jack

Comment: Consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079703/str-shuffle-and-randomness

Comment: It applies [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), coupled with `rand()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `str_shuffle()` uses `rand()` which doesn't produce good quality random numbers as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079997/1338292); if you want a better distribution, you may wish to implement Fisher-Yates yourself and pick a random source of your choice, e.g. [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand):

```
function my_str_shuffle($str)
{
    if ($str == '') {
        return $str;
    }

    $n_left = strlen($str);

    while (--$n_left) {
        $rnd_idx = mt_rand(0, $n_left);
        if ($rnd_idx != $n_left) {
            $tmp = $str[$n_left];
            $str[$n_left] = $str[$rnd_idx];
            $str[$rnd_idx] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

See also [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19222906/1338292) on finding a suitable 0/1 randomiser.

#### Update

Using [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) as your random source:

```
assert($n_left <= 255);
$random = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($n_left);

while (--$n_left) {
    $rnd_index = round($random[$n_left] / 255 * $n_left);
    // ...
}
```